# Should I use JQuery selector to compare elements/values in if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been working with JavaScript and JQuery in past few months and I used many different methods to compare elements and values. Sometimes my values were stored inside of a value in other situations I used JQuery selectors to compare values. So I have a question, is there any difference in between these two? For example something like this:

```
//JQuery selector in if statement
if($('.countRec').children().length == 0){

//Putting value in a variable first
var tbody = $('.countRec');
if(tbody.children().length == 0){
```

Is one method more efficient than other? Is there any potential comparison issues in some situations for these two methods? If anyone can provide explanation please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are going to reuse `$('.countRec')` go ahead with assigning it first!

Comment: [jsLint](http://www.jslint.com/) - use this static analyzer and it will answer some of your questions during development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you *could argue* that your second example is less efficient, because you use a variable to store data, which means you use some memory for it.

In reality, this doesn't make a difference.

**But** considering best practices in your case, you don't want error prone code and go the "extra mile" instead just to make sure you're working on a `property` of your object which actually exists to avoid errors:

```
var tBody,
    children;

tBody = $('.countRec');
children = tbody ? tbody.children() : null;

if(children && children.length == 0){
   // do your thing...
}
```

**Little update:**
Roxoradev mentioned in his answer, that using `$('.yourClass')` could return more than one element, if you have more then one element with a class `yourClass` attached. In this case, you would chain the call `.first()`: `tBody = $('.countRec').first();`

Answer (score 1):

No there is **no difference** between the two solutions.

`$('.countRec')` returns all elements with the class `countRec` and then you store them into the variable `tbody`

Comment: It is true only in case there is only one call for `$('.countRec')`. If you are going to work with this selector later it is recommended to use variable.

Comment: @Sargon Yes of course, Instead of every time to tell jQuery to get variables with the class you store them into a variable

Comment: Well `no difference` is a bit of an overstatement (which isn't exaaaactly true). I mentioned this in my answer.

Comment: @lexith if dive so deep there may be many many difference.I answer on the shallow

Answer (score 1):

if you have 2 .countRec with this:

```
$('.countRec')
```

you get both and if you add a new one you also get the third

if you have 2 .countRec with this:

```
var tbody = $('.countRec')
```

you get both but if you add a new one you still get 2 until you (re)do:

```
var tbody = $('.countRec')
```

Hope you understand